# Meaning of 拳神降臨

Tags: translation, meaning, expressions, sports

During a boxing match there's a banner hanging from a terrace with this expression written on it:

> 拳神降臨

The match in question is a match of the tournament for the best newcomer (日本新人王戦), could it be linked to this? It is not clear if it was hung by some supporters or if it is an official banner of the tournament. The literal translation would be "the advent of a boxing god", but does it have a particular meaning? Is it an expression normally used in sport contexts (for example, could
 you write 野球神降臨)?

[Here's the two pages where the banner can be seen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrsa1.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stick to your literal translation, or rephrase it as you like to match your culture. ～降臨! is a phrase that is like "Here comes ～!" or "We're seeing ～!" and used somewhat slangily on net forums (see [this](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%A5%9E%E9%99%8D%E8%87%A8)). 拳神降臨 is understandable as a phrase on a cheering banner, but it's not common at all. The letters look hand-written by brush, and there is a kanji 会 ("～ club") below 臨 (maybe 後援会 = "supporter's club"?). So I think this is an unofficial banner created by fans. As far as I can tell, this phrase has no particular reference to a famous song, proverb, person, etc. I feel 野球神 is slightly less natural or common than 拳神, but 野球神降臨 is not nonsense, either.

Comment: 「野球神」というくらいなら「球神」になりますよね…

Comment: @broccoliforest それだ！w